# Enter Office 365 Shell Multi-Factor Authentication credentials inside Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I've been trying to find a way to enter the username, password and token code for the Office 365 shell directly into the terminal and not have the normal secondary GUI window pop-up.  Currently I have a basic script that logs in with:

```
Import-Module $((Get-ChildItem -Path $($env:LOCALAPPDATA + "\Apps\2.0\") -Filter Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellModule.dll -Recurse).FullName | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "_none_"} | Select-Object -First 1)
Connect-MSOLService
Import-PSSession (New-ExoPSSession -UserPrincipalName USER@domain.tld) -AllowClobber -DisableNameChecking
```

Is it even possible to use strictly the TUI over the GUI for entering credentials?

Comment: I think it's impossible to connect with 2FA in silent mode. In this case you have to connect with OAuth2 access token.

Answer (score 0):

Don't guess at how to do X or Y. It will just lead you down a very frustrated path. Always look to the help files and online docs.

What you are trying to do is a common practice, these days, and fully documented from Microsoft and many other web resources. There are specific module to assist with this use case.

[Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell using multi-factor authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/mfa-connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

> Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell by using MFA
>
> 1.On your local computer, open the Exchange Online Remote PowerShell Module ( Microsoft Corporation > Microsoft Exchange Online Remote
>   PowerShell Module).
>
> 2.The command that you need to run uses the following syntax:

```
Connect-EXOPSSession -UserPrincipalName <UPN> [-ConnectionUri <ConnectionUri> -AzureADAuthorizationEndPointUri <AzureADUri>]
```

[Connect to Office 365 PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/connect-to-office-365-powershell)

> Step 2: Connect to Azure AD for your Office 365 subscription
>
> ***> To connect to Azure AD for your Office 365 subscription with an
>   account name and password or with multi-factor authentication (MFA),***
>   run one of these commands from a Windows PowerShell command prompt (it
>   does not have to be elevated).

[Exchange Online PowerShell Module has been around since circa 2016 from the MFA PowerShell team](http://aka.ms/exopspreview)

There is even a script from the gallery, that specifically for EXO using MFA.

[Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell using multi-factor authentication (MFA)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Connect-to-Exchange-Online-168c18a7)

> If you want to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to connect to
>   Exchange Online PowerShell, you can't use the instructions at regular
>   Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell to use remote PowerShell to
>   connect to Exchange Online.

Download : [MFA.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Connect-to-Exchange-Online-168c18a7/file/220218/1/MFA.ps1)